# Run PHP from a PNG file on lighttpd

Tags: php, lighttpd

I only need to do this for one file (uptime.php) and it must be requested by using uptime.png.

Adding a rule for all png files in my config file would be suicide.. :P

Comment: Would http://example.com/uptime.png returns the output of uptime.php?
Or do you mean that uptime.php is invoked when a browser looks for http://example.com/uptime.png, but it would get back the content of uptime.png?

Comment: I suspect your trying to create a little uptime image, and run the script to update your up time record in your database, or recreate the image with a new uptime number. Would it not be less hack-ish to just use ajax and have your server hand back the image so javascript can insert it?

Comment: kiamlaluno, either are fine - I just want the browser to see uptime.png, so whichever is easier.

This is just an image displaying the uptime of a server which users of my system can embed in their website. The only reason I want to do this is because browsers never seem to cache PHP images and reload them all the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it does *not* need to be requested by using `uptime.png`: you can use a `.php` extension. As long as your script outputs

```
Content-type: image/png
```

as the MIME type, browsers will recognise the data as an image.

However, if you *really must* use `uptime.png` for the URL, you can use a rewrite rule. For example:

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "^/uptime\.png$" => "/uptime.php" )
```

There is more information about these rewrite rules in the **[Lighttpd Docs::ModRewrite documentation](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/Docs:ModRewrite)**.

Comment: It could be that the OP has some other requirement that mandates what the name must be... but the question is unclear on that point :/

Comment: Do I add that in the lighttpd config file?